# Upgrading to Spring Boot 3 authorizeHttpRequests throwing 403 with oath2ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I'm currently upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring 3 but I'm having issues when upgrading my HTTP Security Config.

I am using Azure B2C for my oauth server and that part is working fine as I can see the valid JWT being returned.
I've changed from using authorizeRequests to authorizeHttpRequests as suggested but all my HTTP requests are returning 403.

If I use authorizeRequests with all of the other Spring 3 suggested updates it still works as expected.

**Configuration File:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("preAuthProvider")
  private AuthenticationProvider preAuthProvider;

  @Value("${oauthTokenChecks.audience}")
  private String audience;

  @Value("${oauthTokenChecks.issuer}")
  private String issuer;
  @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
  private String jwkUri;

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().
        configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated()
        )
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new Auth0TokenConverter());

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(preAuthProvider);
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
  }

  @Bean
  JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder =
        NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkUri).build();

    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience =
        new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);
//    jwtDecoder.setClaimSetConverter(new UsernameSubClaimAdapter());
    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

    return jwtDecoder;
  }
}
```

**Auth Converter:**

```
public class Auth0TokenConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

  @Override
  public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(final Jwt jwt) {

    var emails = jwt.getClaimAsStringList("emails");
    if (emails == null || emails.size() != 1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("One and only one email expected in token claim");
    }

    var user =
        ImplementUser.builder()
            .username(emails.get(0))
            .auth0Id(null)
            .enabled(true)
            .accountNonExpired(true)
            .accountNonLocked(true)
            .credentialsNonExpired(true)
            .build();
    return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, jwt);
  }
}
```

**CustomPreAuthProvider:**

```
@Component("preAuthProvider")
public class CustomPreAuthProvider extends PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider {

  @Autowired
  private CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService userService;

  public CustomPreAuthProvider() {
    super();
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    super.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userService);
  }
}
```

**CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService:**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService
    implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {

  private final AuthUserDetailsService authUserDetailsService;

  @Override
  public final UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token) {
    var principal = (ImplementUser) token.getPrincipal();
    var email = principal.getUsername();
    var user = authUserDetailsService.loadUserDetails(email);

    var implementUser = (ImplementUser) token.getPrincipal();
    return implementUser.toBuilder()
        .firstName(user.getFirstName())
        .lastName(user.getLastName())
        .globalUserId(user.getGlobalUserId())
        .profiles(user.getProfiles())
        .activeProfile(user.getActiveProfile())
        .defaultProfileId(user.getDefaultProfileId())
        .build();

  }
}
```

Below are the error logs

[Log output](https://pastebin.com/VHJXB5iX)

Comment: Have you read the [migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html)?

Comment: @AlexR yes that’s what I followed hence why I’m a bit stumped as to why it’s not working :(

Comment: Reading the logs it seems to me that the `Authenticated` status of your `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` is never set to true. Maybe you have to call `http.
authenticationManager(...)` and set the `AuthenticationManager` you want to use this way?

Comment: @AlexR tried that still same result

Comment: What is the logic inside the `preAuthProvider` class? Can you share its whole implementation?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Added now. They code never gets this far but I expect it to after the Auth0TokenConverter.convert method is ran which returns PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken. The code gets as far as this method.

Comment: same problem here, it just stopped working and i don't even use any authentication